# RecentlyViewed data leakage in unit tests

Tags: unit-test, recentlyviewed

I have some code that queries RecentlyViewed and needed to be unit tested. I noticed a failure today because more records are turning up than expected.

It turns out that if you query RecentlyViewed in a unit test, even without `seeAllData`, you still get actual records back. Should this be considered a bug in Apex?

Comment: I'll ask around. Give me a bit.

Comment: Are the records indicated by the `RecentlyViewed.Id` field accessible in the test case? It's a bit of a special case as a "heterogeneous list of different object types" with a degree of background processing that prunes records out.

Comment: @DanielBallinger It should either be isolated, or mentioned in the docs as being non-isolated. Either way, I feel it's a documentation vs behavior issue.

Comment: +1 I'm all for consistency and documentation of exceptional behavior.

Comment: Charles, go ahead and submit a case, make sure it gets escalated to R&D.

Comment: I believe the records themselves don't show up if query directly from their object table, however I can find their name and ID in `RecentlyViewed`. So yeah this should be either documented or considered a defect. I'll log a case in the Partner portal.

Comment: Just submitted the Partner case, number 18825562.

Comment: Update: The rep replied "I am investigating and checking with internal team of experts. I have replicated in my org as well. I will keep you posted my findings on the same."

Comment: This is now a Known Issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=recentlyviewed-object-contains-customer-data-during-test-execution&Id=a1p3A000000ATEI

Answer (score 1):

This has now been posted as a Known Issue. See here to click that it affects you:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=recentlyviewed-object-contains-customer-data-during-test-execution&Id=a1p3A000000ATEI